# Firefox onpopuphidden on OS X

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm having trouble getting the onpopuphidden event to work under OS X. Here's a very simple XUL file that works for Linux and Windows, but not for OS X

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>

<overlay id="popuphiddenbug-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <menupopup
        id="menu_ToolsPopup">
        <menu
            id="popuphiddenbug-tools"
            label="Choose me">
              <menupopup
                    onpopuphidden="alert ('hidden');"
                    id="popuphiddenbug-menupopup">
                    <menuitem id="popuphiddenbug-menu-item" label="Hide me"/>             
              </menupopup>
          </menu>
      </menupopup>

</overlay>
```

Has anyone else seen this or have a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Is this reproducible with other menupopups or only with `menu_ToolsPopup`?

Comment: It has the same problem with "main-menubar"...

Comment: If I attach an event listener to `menuWebDeveloperPopup`, the `popuphidden` event is fired as expected. The event is not fired when I manually add a new menupopup through dom manipulation, as you experienced. Definitely something is broken (tested under OSX 10.8)

Comment: Yeah, I can attach the listener to higher-level menus/popups and get the correct behavior the first time, but it goes away after that. All a little strange. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: @paa and drsjb80 is this still true? We should file a bug on bugzilla. If you guys don't want to just verify if this is true for me please and I'll file.

Comment: drsjb80 and @paa can you guys please go to this bugzilla topic and post details on how to replicate. I tested this, i created two test cases (at bugzilla topic). I couldn't reproduce the bug. It actually seems window has the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121322

Answer (score 0):

For others to reproduce do this:

Go here: http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/xuledit/xuledit.xul

White list this url with this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-xul-manager/

And paste this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>

<overlay id="popuphiddenbug-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<label menu="menu_ToolsPopup">left clik here for menu</label>
    <menupopup
        id="menu_ToolsPopup">
        <menu
            id="popuphiddenbug-tools"
            label="Choose me">
              <menupopup
                    onpopuphidden="alert ('hidden');"
                    id="popuphiddenbug-menupopup">
                    <menuitem id="popuphiddenbug-menu-item" label="Hide me"/>             
              </menupopup>
          </menu>
      </menupopup>

</overlay>
```

Then click on the label and it will open the menu. then click on "hide me" it should show alert.

I tested on windows. it works

will test on ubuntu 14.04 and mac os x 10.9 tomorrow

Comment: Ubuntu works fine for me; it's only OS X that doesn't... Thanks!